# Split a list item into more list items when a character is found in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a programming language and a problem I am currently facing is how to split a list which contains each line of a text file into more items.

For example:

```
! This is a single line comment

!!!
This line should be ignored
and this one as well
!!!

message_print.Hello World ; message_print.This is multiple line!
```

should render as

```
['! This is a single line comment', '', '!!!', 'This line should be ignored', 'and this one as well', '!!!', '', 'message_print.Hello World', 'message_print.This is multiple line!'
```

I've already tried

```
content = [l.split(',') for l in ','.join(content).split(' ; ')]
```

and

```
content = [x.split(" ; ") for x in content if x.strip()]
```

but as my script is calling 2 of the type above, a list of a list is created which is not what I want.

Also, replacing

```
content = [x.split(" ; ") for x in content if x.strip()]
```

with

```
content = (x.split(" ; ") for x in content if x.strip())
```

just results in a runtime error

Also, here is the code responsible for rendering the code

```
from sys import argv as args
from sys import exit as quit
import syntax

try:
    args[1]
except IndexError:
    print("ERROR: No ROS Code file provided in execution arguments")
    print("Ensure the execution code looks something like this: python run-file.py test.ros")

with open(args[1]) as f:
    ignoreline = False
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content if x.strip()]
    # The code to split a list into more list items goes here
    for value in enumerate(content):
        if not(value[1].startswith('!')) and ignoreline == False:
            firstpart = value[1].split(".")[0]
            lenoffirstpart = len(value[1].split(".")[0])
            afterpart = str(value[1][lenoffirstpart + 1:])
            apwithcomma = afterpart.replace(".", "', '")
            preprint = str(firstpart + "(" + apwithcomma + ")")
            printtext = preprint.replace("(", "('")
            lastprinttext = printtext.replace(")", "')")
            try:
                exec(str("syntax." + lastprinttext))
            except Exception as e:
                template = "ERROR: An error of type {0} occured while running line {1} because {2}"
                message = template.format(
                    type(e).__name__, str(value[0] + 1), str(e.args[0]))
                print(message)
                quit(1)
        elif value[1].startswith('!!!'):
            ignoreline = not(ignoreline)

quit(0)
```

The commands I run to execute the script are as follows

```
@echo off
python run-file.py test.ros
pause
```

And the `test.ros` file is here

```
! This is a single line comment

!!!
This line should be ignored
and this one as well
!!!

message_print.Hello World ; message_print.This is multiple line!
```

If you want to see all of the files involved, take a look at the [Github Commit](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/tree/ce94693f7abd8b642580acdede45901de3801753/src) (only some of them are relavent to solving this question)

Comment: Why don't you split with `\n`

Comment: Have you considered using `re.split`, which can split on a regular expression. `re.split(r'\n|;')`, for example. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split

Comment: How would I do that? Please give me the relevant code to insert.

Comment: Everyone is suggesting what code to use but not where to insert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split on a regular expression pattern.

```
re.split(r' *[;\n] *', source_code)
```

Comment: Where exactly do I insert this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to split the input text on newlines and semicolons, this should do what you want:

```
lines = sum([l.split(';') for l in input_text.splitlines()], [])
```